# Linux find command - find files based on inode and device?

Tags: filesystems, find, inode, stat

I want to find the files with a given inode number. Using find with `-inum` is not entirely helpfull as its listing files with the inode number from every file system/device. How to confine this search to a particular device/fs?

Below is not helpfull -

```
$ sudo find / -inum 2
/
/dev
/dev/shm
/dev/pts/ptmx
/sys/kernel/debug/acpi
/sys/fs
/sys/fs/cgroup
/sys/fs/cgroup/memory/cgroup.procs
/sys/fs/cgroup/pids/cgroup.procs
/sys/fs/cgroup/rdma/cgroup.procs
/sys/fs/cgroup/cpuset/cgroup.procs
/sys/fs/cgroup/devices/cgroup.procs
/sys/fs/cgroup/blkio/cgroup.procs
/sys/fs/cgroup/perf_event/cgroup.procs
/sys/fs/cgroup/freezer/cgroup.procs
/sys/fs/cgroup/hugetlb/cgroup.procs
/sys/fs/cgroup/cpu,cpuacct/cgroup.procs
/sys/fs/cgroup/net_cls,net_prio/cgroup.procs
/sys/fs/cgroup/systemd/cgroup.procs
/sys/fs/cgroup/unified/cgroup.procs
/run
/run/user/1000
find: ‘/run/user/1000/doc’: Permission denied
find: ‘/run/user/1000/gvfs’: Permission denied
/run/user/125
find: ‘/run/user/125/gvfs’: Permission denied
/run/lock
/snap/gtk-common-themes/1506/meta/snap.yaml
/snap/snapd/8790/bin/fc-cache-v6
/snap/snapd/8542/bin/fc-cache-v6
/snap/tusk/29/LICENSES.chromium.html
/snap/gnome-3-34-1804/36/bin/bunzip2
/snap/gnome-3-34-1804/36/bin/bzcat
/snap/gnome-3-34-1804/36/bin/bzip2
/snap/snap-store/467/autostart/setup-autostart
/snap/core18/1885/bin
/snap/core18/1880/bin
/snap/jdownloader2/10/etc/X11
/snap/jdownloader2/12/etc/X11
/snap/core/9804/bin/bash
/proc/fs/nfsd/exports
/proc/sys/fs/binfmt_misc/status
```

#### Below confirms that above listed files are from various devices

```
/etc$ stat /dev/shm /dev /dev/pts/ptmx 
  File: /dev/shm
  Size: 80          Blocks: 0          IO Block: 4096   directory
Device: 1ah/26d Inode: 2           Links: 2
Access: (1777/drwxrwxrwt)  Uid: (    0/    root)   Gid: (    0/    root)
Access: 2020-09-03 14:01:23.968171064 +0530
Modify: 2020-09-03 14:01:53.055049949 +0530
Change: 2020-09-03 14:01:53.055049949 +0530
 Birth: -
  File: /dev
  Size: 4920        Blocks: 0          IO Block: 4096   directory
Device: 6h/6d   Inode: 2           Links: 23
Access: (0755/drwxr-xr-x)  Uid: (    0/    root)   Gid: (    0/    root)
Access: 2020-09-03 11:24:49.787963116 +0530
Modify: 2020-09-03 11:20:16.282767765 +0530
Change: 2020-09-03 11:20:16.282767765 +0530
 Birth: -
  File: /dev/pts/ptmx
  Size: 0           Blocks: 0          IO Block: 1024   character special file
Device: 18h/24d Inode: 2           Links: 1     Device type: 5,2
Access: (0000/c---------)  Uid: (    0/    root)   Gid: (    0/    root)
Access: 2020-09-03 10:18:19.587999997 +0530
Modify: 2020-09-03 10:18:19.587999997 +0530
Change: 2020-09-03 10:18:19.587999997 +0530
 Birth: -
```

Comment: If you know what filesystem you want to search on, why don't you just use that as the start search path and use the `-xdev` primary?

Comment: @Kusalananda, cool - how to prefix, can you give the syntax

Comment: you mean - `find /dev -xdev ...` or `find /proc -xdev ...`

Comment: Exactly, and this is what Stephen is suggesting in their answer too.

Comment: There is also `-samefile` in GNU find

Answer (score 3):

Use `-xdev` (as shown in previous answers to your questions involving `find`):

```
find / -xdev -inum 2
```

Replace `/` with whatever mount point you’re interested in.